# How to Implement a Location Search / Maps in a Django Application

Tags: django, google-maps, django-models

I would like to get some inputs on how should I go about proceeding to achieve the Following.

I want to implement a Web App in Django which will look/search for 'My Supermarket Chain' within 'X KM' of my current location, and choose it and look for products available there.

As an Example, let's make all the Dominos Chain as 'My Supermarket'.

I have already implemented the Part in which the Products in each Stores are set.

How would I go about achieving this?

Let's say I have my Store Model as follow:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    location = ??
```

Should I be adding the Logitude / Latitude of a Dominos Chain to the location field?

or Should I use an API like Google Maps and change the things there?

I am totally blank on how I should go about / learn to achieve this.

Please suggest what all things I would need to learn and how to Apply those so that I can learn it and do it.

Comment: Location should be a ```OneToOneField``` with store. You should look at ```geoDjango``` and ```django-location-field```they may be a better fit for you